# powershell upgrade to 6.2 doesnt upgrade anything (except my mode)

Tags: powershell, powershell-core

I have run the script below

```
iex "& { $(irm https://aka.ms/install-powershell.ps1) } -UseMSI"
```

The msi below gets downloaded and I run it, the wizard finishes without any remarks

https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/releases/download/v6.2.0/PowerShell-6.2.0-win-x64.msi

The only problem is that when I run

```
 "$PSVersionTable.PSVersion"
```

It still says

```
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      1      17763  316
```

and a require-statement in another script also says that I have v5.1...

(yes, I have restarted my machine:))

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try to run `pwsh` or `powershell`?

Comment: PowerShell Core (AKA PowerShell 6+) and PowerShell coexist; Core is not a straight upgrade (yet, anyway).

Comment: Aha... I see... well powershell I guess. I thought the upgrade was an upgrade...silly me. Thanks for the help!

Comment: As for 'well powershell I guess'. Nope, PSCore was always to be cross platform and side by side - by design. The require different .Net versions as well (Core vs Full). This is and was fully documented and advertised by Microsoft upon release.